# Sum or Product of wavefunctions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction

I am confused about how to decide if we need to write a wavefunction as a sum or a product of other "sub-wavefunctions". For example, writing the atomic wavefunction we multiply the individual electronic wavefunctions to construct the atomic wavefunction but in some other places, like in the perturbation theory we use sums of "sub-wavefunctions" to construct the total wavefunction. I know this is a very basic level question but I would be very thankful if somebody can explain this to me.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume a time-independent problem at first and discuss the more general case at the end.

States are vectors in a Hilbert space. This means that once we can find a basis, we can in principle write any state we want in terms of that basis. The question is to find such a basis.

Since our ultimate goal in a quantum system would be to be able to make predictions, we need to have a "nice" expression of our state and to be able to evolve it in time. Frequently our main interest are going to be the states of definite energy, since their time evolution is particularly simple to obtain. Once you get the energy eigenbasis, you can express any other state in terms of energy eigenstates and get time evolution with little trouble. Therefore, our goal is to solve the time-independent Schrödinger equation. Once that is done, we have a basis which is nice o work with and we can write other states in terms of it. When writing said states in terms of this basis, notice we'll be dealing with sums of wavefunctions: the "total" wavefunction is going to be expanded as a linear combination of elements of the bases, hence a sum.

But how can be find such eigenstates? Solving the Schrödinger equation is particularly complicated, specially when we are doing it in more than one dimension. One trick is to use separation of variables: we pick the ansatz that the solution to the time-independent Schrödinger equation can be written in the form $\Psi(r, \theta,\phi) = R(r) \Theta(\theta) \Phi(\phi)$, if we are using spherical coordinates, or maybe $\Psi(x, y, z) = X(x) Y(y) Z(z)$ in Cartesian. The particular coordinates are chosen according to whatever is the most convenient for your problem. A cubical potential has Cartesian-like symmetries, so let's go Cartesian. A hydrogen atom is spherically symmetry, so spherical coordinates it is.

With this ansatz, we can split the difficult-to-solve Schrödinger equation into a few ODEs which are more treatable, and usually will yield special functions as solutions. Once we solve these ODEs we have the explicit expressions for $R(r)$, $\Theta(\theta)$, and $\Phi(\phi)$, for example, and can use them to get the general expression for the wavefunction. During this separation of variables process, a few constants are introduced along the way and that's where the $l$ and $m$ of the hydrogen atom eigenstates come from if you take a purely mathematical point of view.

In summary: you multiply functions together when you are looking for a nice basis. Once you have a nice basis, you add functions to get your wavefunction. (Notice I'm saying functions rather than wavefunctions, for they don't really give all the information you would need to describe the system, so I find it a little weird to use that nomenclature).

What if we have time-dependence and hence are not solving the time-independent Schrödinger equation? Then usually you'll look for a different method to get a nice basis. In perturbation theory, you already have the basis from the unperturbed problem, for example. In a sudden approximation you can use the eigenbasis from before and after the change in the Hamiltonian has taken place, and so on.

Comment: Thank you sir for the best explanation